# Maths strategy game

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

There are 2 players, A and B. A stack of cards is given initially. It may contain an arbitrary number of cards. A player whose turn comes may take between 1 and 5 cards; how many they take is their choice. Player A begins. The last player who can make a move has won the game. How should the players behave? Is there a strategy by which one of the players can force a win, no matter what the opponent does? How does it depend on the initial numbers of cards? For given numbers of cards, how many rounds must at least be played before the game ends? What is the longest possible game?

Comment: I think there is a question that has an implied answer in your questions, but you haven't been explicit about. Do the players know the number of cards in the deck?

Also I'm interested in this problem, but I'm not sure where you have gone with it. What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: It's a piece of work I am doing for college. The deck has an arbitrary number of cards, we are just asked to explore the questions. And I don't really know where to start!

Comment: Start by considering specific simple cases. What happens if the deck contains only one card? What if it contains two?

Comment: I understand those 2 cases, but don't really see how to extend it? Especially for large n

Comment: Try considering a deck with three cards.  Then consider one with four cards.  Then five.  By the time you finish six cards, you may have more understanding.

Comment: Can you give me a hint? Can't quite work it out.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the players know how many cards are in the deck, the winning strategy for this game is to make sure that the number of cards left in the deck at the end of your turn is a multiple of 6.

We arrive at this result by analyzing the endgame. If there are anywhere between 1 to 5 cards at the start of a player's turn, he can take the remaining and win the game. However, if there are 6 cards at the start of the turn, no matter how many cards the player takes, there will be between 1 to 5 cards left which his opponent can take and win the game. Thus 6 cards in the deck at the start of the turn is a losing position, one from which you cannot win assuming optimal play. Therefore, if there are 7 to 11 cards in the deck at the start of a player's turn, he can take enough to leave his opponent with 6 cards, putting his opponent in a losing position. Using a similar logic as before we can deduce that 12 is also a losing position.

We can now postulate that all multiples of 6 are losing positions. We can prove this using induction.

We have shown that 6*1 and 6*2 are losing positions. Now assume 6*k is a losing position. Therefore if there are 6k+1, 6k+2, 6k+3, 6k+4 or 6k+5 cards left at the start of a player's turn he can remove the appropriate number of cards to leave the opponent with 6*k cards, which is a losing position. Thus if there are 6(k+1) cards left at the start of a player's turn, no matter how many cards he takes, his opponent has the opportunity to make sure that the number of cards left in the deck at the end of his turn is 6*k cards, a losing position. Therefore 6(k+1) is also a losing position, completing the proof by mathematical induction.

From this, we can infer that assuming optimal play, if the number of cards left in the deck is a multiple of 6 then player B wins, otherwise player A wins.